# Extension of laplace method's

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, laplace-method

It is well known that the integral $\int_a^b e^{-n \cdot f(x)}dx$ can be approximate by $\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{n|f''(x_0)|}}e^{-n\cdot f(x_0)}$ at $x_0$ the maximum of $f(x)$ in $(a,b)$ (for large $n$..).

What can be said about approximating $\int_a^b n^{g(x)}e^{-n \cdot f(x)}dx$?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1052676/5531) asks about a case when $g(x) = -x$, $a=0$, and $b=\infty$.  For that xample it's shown that the factor $n^{-x}$ doesn't shift the saddle point much and can just be replaced with $n^{-x_0}$ to get the correct first approximation.  Higher-order terms in the asymptotic expansion are different from those for usual Laplace-type integrals, though.